# How to execute shell script using soapUI

Tags: shell, groovy, soapui

I have one shell script like sample.sh . I want to execute this script using soapUI. How to execute it using soap UI??

Answer (score 3):

You can use Groovy Step to do this. Something like:

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sample.sh")
p.waitFor()
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to get results as a string:

**Windows:**

```
def result = 'cmd /c sample.bat'.execute().text
```

**Shell:**

```
def result = 'sh -c sample.sh'.execute().text
```

Please note, the "cmd /c" or "sh -c" part is needed usually to execute a file. If you want to run simple internal commands such as "dir" or "ls", then it won't be necessary.

Comment: In batch file I have  3 lines :                                                                     1. "cmd /K start "  + "plink.exe  -ssh root@IP -pw password"                                                   2. sh sample.sh                                                                                                   3. exit                                                                                                                                                         Only 1st line is getting executed after loggin to server its not executing second line.

Comment: That's obviously because line#1 take you to a new session, where the other lines wait for this session to end to run. There is an easy way to do this. It seems you are using Windows, then you can use putty as a medium. I wrote a blog about this a while ago, hope it helps: http://qatesterblog.blogspot.com/2014/12/ssh-and-remote-commands-during.html

Comment: @SiKing , thanks for the note. It should be -c for shell/bash . That simply states to wait till the execution finishes.

Comment: Also: `result` gets assigned `.text` of the execution, and then you do `result.waitFor()`?!?! String has no waitFor() method!